# Best practice to organize SpringBoot Events/EventListeners

Tags: java, spring-boot, events, design-patterns, event-handling

I think this is strongly related to Observer and Publish/Subscribe patterns but since I have still not seen production code using it, I have some questions on how you guys organize your code when using events and eventListeners in SpringBoot (though I believe it can be extended to any languages/frameworks).

Let's say I have 3 classes and their respective services :

```
Foo with FooService
Bar with BarService
Baz with BazService
```

When FooService creates a Foo object, I want BarService and BazService to execute some code to update their respective tables for exemple so I publish the `FooCreatedEvent`.

What are the best practices here since I have 2 different services ?

Solution 1 :

One class encapsulating everything

```
public class FooEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;
    @Autowired
    private BazService bazService;

    @EventListener
    public void handleFooCreatedEvent(FooCreatedEvent event) {
       barService.doSomething(event);
       bazService.doSomething(event);
    }

}
```

Solution 2 :

2 classes each encapsulating its own service

```
public class BarEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private BarService barService;

    @EventListener
    public void handleFooCreatedEvent(FooCreatedEvent event) {
       barService.doSomething(event);
    }

}

public class BazEventListener {

    @Autowired
    private BazService bazService;

    @EventListener
    public void handleFooCreatedEvent(FooCreatedEvent event) {
       bazService.doSomething(event);
    }

}
```

I like solution 2 in terms of design, but I think it can be a bit confusing to have `BarEventListener` handle `FooEvents`

What do you guys think ?

Answer (score 0):

The downside of the first solution is that the class must be edited every time a new service wants to listen, so it will likely violate the Open/Closed Principle. The downside of the second solution is that it creates a parallel inheritance hierarchy that doubles the number of classes needed, and still must be edited for new services to listen.

But the services themselves can implement their own `@EventListener` methods. That way new services don't need to edit other classes and class hierarchies. If `BarService` wants to listen to `FooCreatedEvent` then it can implement its own listener method inside itself, rather than in a separate class.